# xps 15 9950 ubuntu 14.04 no audio input

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, soundcard, xps

I am running 14.04 on an XPS 15 9950 (late 2015). The audio card is an HDA Intel PCH, the cpu is the Intel Skylake.
My problem is that no audio input device is detected.

running alsamixer and checking capture devices (F4), gives me following output:

```
This sound device does not have any capture controls.
```

anyone had a similar problem? This happens after a more or less clean installation of ubuntu, son I don't believe that I screwed up something before.

Comment: by "no audio input device is detected" I mean the internal mic, not external devices that can be detected.